Why declare a local anonymous function and return its output?
I have seen sometimes this code in web pages:
  function foo(left, right){
    return foo = function(left_2, right_2){
      left_2 = left_2 - 67;
      let value = str_array[left_2];
      return value;

    }
    ,foo(left, right);
  }

What's the point of doing this? why not just return str_array[left]?
It looks a bit like the idea of using a self-executing function, which is usually done to prevent namespace collisions, but what's the point of doing it inside of a function declaration?

It doesn't seem to make any sense to do this. Either it wasn't transcribed correctly so something was lost, or the original author had some misunderstanding.

This does not "declare a local anonymous function". It overwrites the foo that was declared by the outer function.

"I have seen sometimes code like this in web pages" - what exactly do you have seen?

Caching some expensive one-time operation, like a couple of existing answers have suggested, is a likely candidate – but it doesn’t make sense for the example in your question, so you should edit in what Bergi asked for, i.e. a specific example and not just a “like”.

The only place I've seen this pattern is in highly obfuscated code.

The exact code makes even less sense than the other one, since it doesn't even use the second parameter.

Is this exact exact? Nothing inside the outer function omitted? Because in that case, it could be a lot of things, e.g. the suboptimal output of a compiler or part of an obfuscation attempt – but unnecessary in practical code that you’re writing, yes. In isolation, it’s equivalent to function foo(left, right) { return str_array[left - 67]; }.

This is a programming pattern called "function memoization" where a function, upon first call, performs something (often something time-consuming or computationally expensive), while also redeclaring itself on this first call.
This can be beneficial if the first call's results can be cached and used in subsequent calls.
Imagine something like this, where a function is supposed to work on dynamic data retrieved from a REST endpoint, then answer questions on that data:
function getAdress(name) {
  const responsePromise = fetch('/api/addresses');
  return getAdress = async function(name) {
    const response = await responsePromise;
    // more code that retrieves the address by name from the response
    // on subsequent calls after the first won't have to
    // fetch data any more.
    return address;
  }, getAdress(name);
}

Here's an exhaustive article on the concept: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-memoize-in-javascript-51d07d19430e/

the example does seem a bit unconventional and may not have a clear advantage over a simple function implementation like directly returning left + right
but still This pattern can be powerful in certain situations but it's not always necessary there reasons you might need to use this pattern optimization after initialization If the initial function needs to perform some setup that only needs to happen once this pattern ensures that setup happens on the first call and subsequent calls are optimized or you just want to allows a function to modify its own behavior after the first execution

Please consider using proper punctuation and formatting for your answers. As it stands, it is really unnecessarily hard to read.
